# SignalR Self Hosting With WCF Service and Clients Would be Desktop Users

Tags: wcf, signalr

My Scenerio is that i need a SignalR self Hosted WCF Service that response and sends message to all connected users that came from Winform or WPF.

I have tried alot as follows:

- I have Created WCF service with SignalR Self Hosting code as below which contains 3 Classes and 1 Interface.

```
        namespace SignalRServiceClass
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISignalRServiceClass
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetsMessage(string name);
        [OperationContract]
        void Configuration(IAppBuilder app);

        [OperationContract]
        void Send(string name, string message);
    }
}
namespace SignalRServiceClass
{
    public class SignalRServiceClass : ISignalRServiceClass
    {
        public string GetsMessage(string name)
        {
            return "Message From Service " + name + "!";
        }
    }
}
namespace SignalRServiceClass
{
    class ClassHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}

namespace SignalRServiceClass
{
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           // app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
           // app.MapSignalR();
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
                {
                    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                    var hubConfiguration= new HubConfiguration
                    {
                        EnableDetailedErrors=true,
                        EnableJSONP= true
                    };
                    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

And Secondly Winform Client. I am confused here that how to manage the client code here but i put some code for testing as below.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(test.GetsMessage("This is the Test Message"));

            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:50172/");
            var serverHub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MessageRecievingHub");
            serverHub.On("broadCastToClients", message => MessageBox.Show(message));
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        }
```

Please guide me in this manner.
Your Help will be appreciated. I have tried and googled alot but in vain.

Thanks alot in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

You do not want SignalR, you need XSockets [WCF sample](http://xsockets.net/api/guides/boosting-a-wcf-to-realtime)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. but can you please tell me . XSockets can work between different WinForm/WPF clients..? because i don't need Web Chat i actually needs Desktop APP to Desktop APP just Like Skype or others...

Comment: My Second Question is : Can XSockets will work between two projects having different solutions.???

Comment: Yes, XSockets can communicate between anything that has .NET4 or Mono and TCP/IP. XSockets is client/server, machine 2 machine, peer 2 peer.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR and WCF don't interoperate in this way, and don't really need to. If you're using SignalR, there's no reason to use WCF- you can publish your hub on IIS or self-hosted (see the Getting Started tutorial and the Self-Host tutorial at asp.net/signalr), and connect to it with desktop or JavaScript/HTML clients.

Comment: thank you for the response but as i saw in different examples . SignalR can't communicate with two projects having different solutions.. If i create Desktop in One solution and Web in other solution then it can't communicate with each other. can you help me out in this matter. guideline and tutorial links will be appreciated..

Comment: There's no reason why you can't host a SignalR client in multiple application types- SignalR exposes its endpoint and doesn't care what sort of client connects to it. Our tutorials only deal with web clients, but you can read up about creating a .NET client here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a .NET client application to communicate with your SignalR server - below is a simple WinForm .NET C# client that sends and receives a SignalR message:

```
namespace SignalrTestClient
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/");
        IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        await hubConnection.Start();
        hubProxy.On("addMessage", message => onData(message));
        await hubProxy.Invoke("Send", "Hello SignalR Server!");
    }

    private void onData(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
}
```

In your SignalR server you just need the following hub class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received a message from a client");
        if (message.Contains("Hello")) {
            Clients.All.addMessage("Well hello there client!");
        }
    }
}
```

It is also possible to create a C++ client for SignalR